# iPhone: Do I have to have images for both retina and non-retina for all image?

Tags: iphone, ios, retina-display

I heard that you need to create images for both retina and non-retina.
And you need to name them like image@2x.png for retina and image.png for non-retina.

But I want use image.png for both retina and non-retina.
And scale it down in program because it is easier to adjust size of image by code than by recreating images with paint tool.

It is possible to do so using this code:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 40, 40);
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

image.png is scaled down to button size or image view size.

Is this a common way?
Does this way have any disadvantages?
Does apple reject if application does't have both image.png and image@2x.png?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[EDIT1 - SPECIAL CASE]**

There is a SPECIAL case however to this problem.  Since Apple' current 2x algorithm is essentially a pixel doubling (in each direction), if you images are made of of only vertical and horizontal lines, then I would go about providing those images as the 1x and let the API auto upscale those, an example would be an image for a button that looks like this

[image]

As this will have zero problems upscaling and still looking very crisp!!! (Tested on both iPhones, as well as both iPads)

**[ORIGINAL]**
If you are simply doing it for display, then one way would be to simply provide the image as it should be for the retina only, and allow the UIImageView to scale down the image automatically for the non-retina displays.  It WILL do this and will NOT be rejected by apple.

For the retina display, the UIImageView will naturally take up the space of 2x the pixels in each direction, thus when the image is read in for display on a retina display, the API will recognize that no scaling needs to occur!!!

Be careful though!!!  Downscaling images lets say for buttons can have effects that make your images or buttons come out looking unclean / pixelated.  This is why it is "recommended" to provide both, is with lets say a vector based image, you would be able to generate the highest quality image for a given resolution.  Kinda depends on how you want to use the images.

As a side note.  I would recommend that if you do choose the resizing option, that you try to recognize the device' screen resolution up front and resize the images (if necessary in my case for the SMALLER resolutions) only once at initialization into the button or UIImageView etc... so that you won't suffer the slower performance each time it needs to be rendered to screen.

Comment: The above scaling images down for actual images versus the special case is what I used when I was obtaining thumbnail images for a UITableView from the web.  The Web service scaled them to the retina resolution, when they got to me, I recognized the screen res, then downscaled the images again to 1x res (if non retina) prior to storing UIImage into the UIImageView on the table.  This gave the best potential resolution for both cases, and still kept the speed to the best possible, no drag whatsoever!!!

Comment: thanks for helpful advice and useful information.
I will create only `image.png` which has x2 pixels.

Comment: Sorry for pinging an old thread. So basically if I want to display for example Twitter avatars that I got as 400x400, simply resizing the UIImageView's frame to 200x200 will make it look good in both retina and non retina displays, isn't it?

Comment: you dont HAVE to, but it usually makes the app look better between devices.  It also VERY MUCH matters what your images look like.  In one of my apps, there were a whole bunch of images that had nothing but vertical and horizontal lines, not really anything rounded or with much shading, so it doesnt make sense for me to re-create doubly sized images.

Comment: Good answer! 
On a similar note, I have two buttons (of different sizes) but with identical backgrounds...
Should I make two seperate sets of images, of make one set (for the larger button) and scale it for the smaller button?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you may not want to hear this but it is best to use a paint tool. If you have the device resize the images each time, it'll slow down your app - depending on how frequently you perform this task. I don't think apple will reject you for not including @2x images. I've forgotten them before with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include @2x images then your app will work both for retina and non-retina iphones. Apple is not going to reject your binary for this. 
The only disadvantage is that instead of good quality images for retina you will be displaying normal images.

Comment: THIS ISNT CORRECT.  You can provide the 2x images (without the @2x in the filename), and the API will downscale for the lower resolutions, you don't HAVE to provide the 1x images and upscale.  But either way there may be unwanted artifacts.

Comment: @trumpetlicks I didn't say that you can't use larger images, weather 2x 3x 4x, but if you use `@2x` suffix then and don't provide 1x images then your app will show images. It's true that using larger images without `@2x` suffix will make you app run both on retina/non-retina devices but it may hit the performances as you're using larger images in non-retina devices